# Como faço para guardar no banco de dados, quando um "usuário" ou "admin" editam ou cadastram um novo item?

Tags: php, mysql

Quero saber como faço pra guardar as ações,tipo, quando admin, loga e desloga, altera um cadastro ou cria um novo cadastro??

Comment: Exemplo: da mesma forma que você faz a autenticação buscando no banco de dados, você faz um `insert` em uma tabela "`log`" com os dados que você quer.

Comment: Ainda não consegui entender muito bem sobre o "log", to fazendo várias pesquisas, mas to perdido

Comment: Referente ao "log", eu tenho que fazer uma consulta na tabela de usuarios antes de fazer o insert na tabela logs?

Comment: Cara, log é apenas informação. Da mesma forma que você tem um registro de "cadastros", que você insere o que você quer, o "log" é mesma coisa. Aí de onde, em qual momento e quais dados você vai puxar, você que define. Ou pode fazer uma trigger, se aquilo irá lhe atender.

Comment: Trigger no caso, eu só guarda as alterações feitas direto no banco certo ? Eu quero salvar as ações que fazem nas páginas...

Comment: Então... pode ser por trigger ou por query. Mas acho que está te faltando conhecimento na teoria sobre banco, triggers. Sua pergunta é ampla, mas ao mesmo tempo simples. Já mostraram as 2 formas nas respostas.

Comment: Consegui aqui rs, pensei melhor e deu certo, meu problema agora é com a data, que está salvando 0000-00-00 00000

Comment: Opa, legal! Veja qual das respostas te ajudou, marque como resolvida clicando no " V ". Para te ajudar com essa data, faça uma nova pergunta, mostre o código como está, detalhe bem que o pessoal com certeza responde essa rapidão! Boa sorte com seu projeto!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pelo o que eu estou vendo voce quer criar tipo log tenho algo parecido em um script meu e é assim cria a funcao :

```
function addlog($msg)
{
global $pdo;
$msg = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($msg));
$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO fun_log SET msg='".$msg."', data='".time()."'");
}
```

depois é só criar a tabela :

```
CREATE TABLE `fun_log` (
`id` int(255) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`msg` text NOT NULL,
`data` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

ai quando vc quiser registrar é só chamar tipo assim :

```
$msg = "Fulano fez tal coisa";
addlog($msg);
```

só uma observação se você for usar isso apenas para aprendizado e testes ok mas se for para algo mais serio recomendo melhorar o INSERT deixar mais seguro para não tomar sql injection exemplo se você usa o pdo passa os dados para o bindparam sei que é só uma função de log mais segurança em primeiro lugar, depois é só criar uma paginação com os logs

Comment: Thiago, Não entendi muito bem, sou novo nessa área. Esse script ai que vc mandou, ele guarda esses registros no banco de dados ?

Comment: exatamente ele registrar o que o usuário faz mas somente quando vc chama exemplo você tem uma página painel e você quer saber quando os usuários entrarem nela aí faz tipo assim : `<?phpif($pg=="painel") { $msg="fulano entrou no painel"; addlog($msg);   .......}?>`

Comment: Acho que entendi, vou só dar uma pesquisada sobre o Trigger pois achei muito interessante a forma de criar ma tabela de histórico com ele, mas vou tentar fazer da forma que me passou também, obrigado pela resposta Thiado !

Comment: o trigger ele trabalha somente com banco de dados se é só o que você quer é uma boa opção mais se vc quer informações mais específicas tipo como falei seria uma boa opção desse jeito

Comment: Ah sim, entendi Thiago, vou tentar dessa forma, e te dou um retorno !

Comment: Thiago, voltei rs... Não to conseguindo salvar nada na tabela de log, eu queria também salvar tudo por coluna, exemplo: id_usuario[nome do usuario que fez a alteração], nivel_usuario[nivel do usuario que fez a alteração], cartão_alterado[numero do cartão alterado] e por ai vai, tem como fazer assim?

Comment: claro que tem é só depois que executar alteração chamar a função para chamar o nome do usuário eu tenho criado uma função que identifica o id do usuário e mostra o nome, coisa simples só um select mesmo aí adiciono esse função a uma variável ex: `$nome = getuid($uid);` aí se eu quizer é só chamar assim a função `$msg = "$nome modificou tal coisa" ; addlog($msg) ;`  se não de certo chamando $nome tente %nome%

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o que você procura é isso [Triggers](https://www.devmedia.com.br/mysql-triggers/8088)
Você pode criar uma nova tabela de logs e a cada insert, delete ou update o trigger criado no banco adiciona automatica na tabela logs a alteração feita e a data por exemplo.

-- No seu caso ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
CREATE TRIGGER NOME_TRIGGER 
AFTER INSERT ON TB_CLIENTE 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TB_REGISTROS SET CAMPO_DA_TABELA_REGISTROS = NEW.CLIENTE_NOME;
END;
```

-- O After(depois) ali encima significa que o Trigger vai ser executada repois da inserção
-- Também poderias ser usado o before(antes) para a trigger ser executada antes do insert,update ou delete

-- "Insert on" está dizendo que o Trigger vai ser disparado quando ocorrer um insert em tb_cliente
 -- Poderia também ser usado "update on" ou "delete on"

-- "For Each Row" diz que o Trigger Devera Executar esse comando para cada novo insert

-- A Palavra "begin" marca o inicio do comando e o "end" Termino.

-- A Palavra Reservada "new" Se Refere Ao Novo Registro Que Foi Inserido, no exemplo ele vai inserir na Tabela registro o nome do novo cliente. Também poderia ser usado "old" para Pegar o valor antigo de um update.

Pra entender melhor leia [aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/mysql-triggers/8088)

Comment: No caso eu tendo uma tabela de usuarios e uma tabela de cadastros_cliente, eu crio mais uma tabela "registros" e ai uso esse Triggers, nos inserts ou updates, das tabelas usuarios e cadastros ?

Comment: Eu queria apenas deixar registrado em uma tabela, todas as vezes que um funcionário logar e deslogar de um sistema, e também guardar qualquer alteração que ele faz nesse sistema...

Comment: Fiz as alterações na resposta, caso ainda não tenha entendido, acesse o link que eu coloquei lá, vai te explicar mais detalhadamente.

Comment: Eu posso usar ele em duas tabelas ? Por exemplo, como dito, tenho as duas tabelas, a de usuários que contém: id, nome, usuario, nivel_usuario('admin','user_comum'),status('ativo','inativo')... e também a tabela, cadastro, que contém o id, id_cliente, informacao_cliente e etc, ai queria fazer a junção que pega, o id, nivel, e nome do usuario que fez a alteração no cliente

Comment: Com o trigger você consegue registrar as alterações feitas nas tabelas de forma automática no proprio banco de dados, mas como ela não aceita parâmetro não teria como você saber quem editou tal registro, mas você ainda pode tentar com **Stored Procedures**, mas ficaria um trabalho mais manual e você teria de chamar a procedure pelo nome no php, assim `$con->query("minhaProcedure($parametro)");`

Comment: @murilo Dê uma lida em [Stored Procedures](https://www.devmedia.com.br/stored-procedures-no-mysql/29030)

Comment: Claro, vou ler agora mesmo, obrigado !!